# How to inspect a running Docker container

Tags: docker

I've started a Docker container with [tutum/lamp](https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-lamp) image with this command:

`docker run -d -P --name design_patterns -v /public_html:/app tutum/lamp`

As you can see, I mounted my local folder /public_html to /app directory in the container.

Having started this container, I realized that PHP files that are present in /public_html are not accessible from the browser. I should have probably mounted my local folder to a different location in the container.

How can I inspect the running container to check where my local data should be loaded?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can do 2 things:

`docker inspect design_patterns`

will show you some info about the running container

or just get into the container

`docker exec -it design_patterns bash`

this will drop you into a bash shell into the container, then you can inspect the current state with regular bash commands

Comment: Btw, after inspecting the container, I confirmed that I mounted the data volume incorrectly, is it possible for me to restart the same container with different mounting options, or do I have do I have to kill and run a container again ?

Comment: you have to `stop` it, then `rm` it and then `run` it again